# I can't reach my own site through Tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-routing, socks

I'm having trouble to reach my home server through Tor:
I have the Tor browser bundle and can reach all sites I normally visit.
I also am able to reach my site while not proxying my traffic through Tor.
Only with my own site Tor says:

> Rejecting SOCKS request for anonymous connection to private address

And also: have tried resolving or connecting to address '[scrubbed]' at 3 different places. Giving up.
I have a 'myname'.ddns.net dynamic dns set up. and also the port I try to reach is uncommon (9091)
Do I have to open this port somewhere else than my ISP router?
I have the impression that something is blocking my incoming traffic, but the port forwarding on my router is set correctly.

Comment: Can you reach your home server remotely (from work, a friend's house, an Internet cafe, etc) without using Tor? Also, it sounds like you're using your site's local private address with Tor. That won't work. You should be using the public 'myname'.ddns.net address.

Comment: Yes, I can reach it trough internet (friends house etc) not from work because they block the port that I use. That is the reason I want to use TOR for this purpose. I am using the ddns address, and not the local ip. I use the 'myname'.ddns.net address from other places then home without tor and that works fine. It is really TOR or its included proxy that is blocking my traffic. And the strangest thing is is that other "normal" sites are perfectly accessible trough tor at work.

Comment: Is there a way to PM? I could send you the actual 'myname'.ddns.net address so you can check the accesibility through Tor and the normal internet yourself.

Comment: I don't think that Tor.SE has private messages. You could try to access your site via Tor at a friend's house. Maybe the simplest solution would be picking a port for your site that your work firewall allows. Maybe Tor's DNS servers don't handle *.ddns.net well. Anyone?

Comment: I already tried it via tor from home, and that didn't work either. Changing the port to 80 won't work because my ISP won't allow port forwarding below port 1024 (they don't want users to run home servers). I already had an application work on port 8080 through tor. My current application is on port 9091, I suppose that that wouldn't make such a big difference. I also tried to connect using my public IP instead of the ddns.net (also from friends house) and that worked also perfectly when not using tor and didn't work with tor.

Comment: You say that you can connect "using my public IP ... from friends house ... when not using tor" but "didn't work with tor". Do I have that right? If so, the problem is not ddns.net. Go back to port 8080 and see if that works. Maybe Tor reserves ports over 9000?

Comment: Ok, I'll try that this evening when I get home.

Comment: I changed the listening port to 8081, also changed the port forwarding settings in my router to this port. Still not working. when I use 'myname'.ddns.net:8081 from home it works, with tor it doesn't. I am absolutely sure ddns is set up with my public address. maybe you guys can try to connect to http://struyfsjan.ddns.net:8081 you should get a login popup. pls let me know if you can connect.

Comment: user@debian:~$ wget http://struyfsjan.ddns.net:8081/
--2014-07-15 02:09:36--  http://struyfsjan.ddns.net:8081/
Resolving struyfsjan.ddns.net (struyfsjan.ddns.net)... 84.194.177.8
Connecting to struyfsjan.ddns.net (struyfsjan.ddns.net)|84.194.177.8|:8081... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Comment: so you are unable to connect without tor? Would this be a normal response if a login is needed when connecting? If you connect in a browser you should get a prompt for login and pw.

Comment: I found the problem, it was not tor related: apparently my raspberry pi linux distribution came with a preconfigured iptables. Being new to linux this was hard to figure out. Sorry to have bothered you :-) I got it working now. Thanks for the support!

Comment: Please consider how to edit your question in a useful way, and to avoid confusion. The answer can then be adapted to the revised question.

Comment: Done, question modified.

Answer (score 1):

Private addresses are addresses within the ranges, 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, and 192.168.0.0/16.
To put it simply these addresses are not designed for use in and are not usable in the public internet (at least not without issue).
If the address you are trying to connect to is within any of these ranges then Tor won't be able to connect to them. This is what I suspect is happening to you.
The reason you can connect to the server when not using Tor is that you're not connecting over the internet; you're connecting directly through your private network.

To get around this you need to set your server up with a public IP address. You already have a public IP address as you're successfully using the internet. Configuring your server to be connectable using that address is out of the scope of Tor, but you can probably find a tutorial or two by <s>googling</s> duckduckgo'ing it.

Comment: The server that I am trying to reach is at home. I can reach it from a friends house, not from work because the port 9091 is blocked. that is why I want to use TOR. By the way: I do use a dynamic dns. This also works, but not with TOR.